# Force derived to class to have constructor with predefined signature

Tags: inheritance, typescript1.5

Is it possible in typescript to force all derived classes to have a constructor with a predefined signature?

Answer (score 3):

If the constructor of the parent class requires some arguments, developers will be forced to pass those arguments using the super constructor:

```
class Base {
    constructor(a : string, b : string) {
        // ...
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor(a : string, b : string) {
        super(a,b); // Error if super is not invoked
    }
}
```

If the developers don't explicitly declare the `Derived` class constructor they will get an error when creating an instance:

[image]